# Unable to execute query due to double quotes surrounding table name in Slick with SQL Server profile

Tags: sql-server, scala, slick

I am using Slick with SQL Server profile. I am encountering below error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Invalid object name 'application.sch.place_table'.
```

when trying to execute `TableQuery.result` (see `exec1` in code below). But, this does not happen for plain SQL (see `exec2` in code below).

```
case class Source(rowId: Long, placeId: Int)

class SourceTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[Source](tag, "application.sch.place_table") {
  def rowId = column[Long]("RowID")
  def placeId = column[Int]("place_id")

  def * = (rowId, placeId).mapTo[Source]
}

object SlickTest extends App {

  val db: SQLServerProfile.backend.DatabaseDef =
    Database.forURL(
      url = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:3000/place_db",
      user = "user",
      password = "user123",
      driver = "slick.jdbc.SQLServerProfile"
    )

  lazy val sources = TableQuery[SourceTable]

  val exec1 = Await.result(
      db.run(sources.result), Duration.create(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
  ) // NOT OK

  val exec2 = Await.result(
    db.run {
      sql"""SELECT "RowID", "place_id" FROM application.sch.place_table """
        .as[(Long, Int)]
    },
    Duration.create(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
  ) // OK
}
```

It seems that this issue is because the SQL generated from `TableQuery` has its table name surrounded by double quotes i.e.

```
println(sources.result.statment.mkString) //select "RowID", "place_id" from "application.sch.place_table"
```

How to solve this issue?

Comment: You've tagged the table name as "application.sch.place_table" which is why it's getting quoted in the generated query. To [tag a schema name](https://scala-slick.org/doc/3.0.0/schemas.html) you'd define it `Table[Source](tag, Some("sch"), "place_table")`.

Comment: Modifying it to `Table[Source](tag, Some("sch"), "place_table")` will generate `select "RowID", "hotel_id" from "sch"."place_table"` and I still have the same error:

**Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Invalid object name 'sch.place_table'.**

Comment: Is there an `sch.place_table` in the `place_db` database? If it's in a different database then you probably need a different database connection/DatabaseRef.

Comment: Yes, there is. That's why `exec2` is able to execute properly. Even `exec1` is going to execute properly if I call _overrideStatements()_ :
`val exec1 = Await.result(db.run(sources.result.overrideStatements(Seq("SELECT rowid, place_id FROM application.sch.place_table"))),Duration.create(1,TimeUnit.MINUTES))`

Answer (score 0):

After some research and trial and errors, it turned out that I need to specify the database name in the connection string and tag the schema name.

So from my code above, I need to change it to:

```
class SourceTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[Source](tag, Some("sch"), "place_table")
```

and

```
  val db: SQLServerProfile.backend.DatabaseDef =
    Database.forURL(
      url = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:3000/place_db;databaseName=application",
      user = "user",
      password = "user123",
      driver = "slick.jdbc.SQLServerProfile"
    )
```